# Parse HTML into NSAttributedString with San Francisco Font? (iOS 9)

Tags: ios, ios9, accessibility, nsattributedstring, uifont

I need to parse basic HTML Strings containing `<b>`(bold), `<i>`(italic), and `<u>`(underline) tags, nothing else, just those simple tags.

Right now I can only get the `<u>`(underline) tags to render properly in the `NSAttributedString`, when using the new `San Francisco` in `iOS 9`.

I really need to get `<b>`(bold) and `<i>`(italic) to render as well.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
let text = "<i>Any</i> <b>Text</b> <u>that's basic HTML</u>"
let font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleBody)

let modifiedFont = NSString(format:"<span style=\"font-family: '-apple-system','HelveticaNeue'; font-size: %f \">%@</span>",
font.pointSize, text) as String

let data = (modifiedFont as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data: data!, options:
            [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute : NSUTF8StringEncoding,
                NSFontAttributeName : font ],
            documentAttributes: nil)
```

But unfortunately the `<i>`(italic) and `<b>`(bold) tags never render, only `<u>`(underline) renders correctly.

This same exact method used to work on `iOS 8` with `Helvetica-Neue` font, but it's not working with the new `iOS 9` `San Francisco` font

Help me get `<b>`(bold) and `<i>`(italic) to render properly in an `NSAttributedString`!

**Update**: I am using Dynamic Text throughout the application as well. This may be a cause of why things aren't working...

Comment: Check out my answer below. It gives a good tip for dealing with both Dynamic Text and NSAttributedString.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using both `NSAttributedString` and `DynamicType` in the app is what caused the problem.

As it turns out you **NEED** to re-parse/render your `String` after receiving the `UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification`. You CANNOT retain the `NSAttributedString` and then use it to reset the text in your `UILabel`. You must re-parse/render the `NSAttributedString`.

Brief Example:

```
public override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //register be notified when text size changes.
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("didChangePreferredContentSize:"), name: UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
}

// The action Selector that gets called after the text size has been changed.
func didChangePreferredContentSize(notification: NSNotification) {
    self.myLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleSubheadline)
    //
    // DO NOT do this:
    // self.myLabel.attributedText = self.myAlreadyRenderedText
    //
    //Make sure you re-render/parse the text into a new NSAttributedString.
    //Do THIS instead:
    self.myLabel.attributedText = self.renderAttributedText(str)
}

//Our method to render/parse the HTML tags in our text. Returns an NSAttributedString.
func renderAttributedText(str: String) -> NSAttributedString? {
    let text = "<i>Any</i> <b>Text</b> <u>that's basic HTML</u>"
    let font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleBody)

    let modifiedFont = NSString(format:"<span style=\"font-family: '-apple-system','HelveticaNeue'; font-size: %f \">%@</span>",font.pointSize, text) as String

    let data = (modifiedFont as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data: data!, options:
        [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
            NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute : NSUTF8StringEncoding,
            NSFontAttributeName : font ],
        documentAttributes: nil)

    return attributedString
}

deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```